# Muro e parete, la differenza

Tags: word-choice, single-words

Sono stato a casa di una mia amica. Ho chiamato la parete della casa muro, ma sua figlia mi ha corretto. Che differenza c'è tra una parete e un muro? Ho sempre pensato che il muro fosse il solido e la parete la superficie del muro. Ci sono per caso variazioni regionali sull'uso di questa parola?

Grazie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La differenza tra muro e parete è molto semplice:

un muro indica una recinzione, una barriera, ad esempio il muro tra Messico e Stati Uniti, tanto per citare qualcosa di attuale.

Una parete è, in questo caso, una componente strutturale di una casa o più in generale di un edificio.

È anche vero che si usa dire "mura di casa", ma anche qui prende il senso di barriera ed indica quindi una sorta di protezione.